# Avengers, Fantastic Four and Guardians of the Galaxy Timeline

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, guardians-of-the-galaxy-1, fantastic-four

Are '[Guardians of the Galaxy](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2015381/)', '[Fantastic Four](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1502712/)' and '[Avengers](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0848228/)' movies set in the same timeline?

Comment: I assume you're referring to the movies and not the comics?

Comment: Yes. I know that the comics are set in the same timeline but are the movies set in the same timeline?

Comment: What about the the upcoming Fantastic Four movie which is in production?

Comment: *Avengers 2* and *Guardians of the Galaxy*: yep. *Fantastic Four*: nope.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The following movies and TV shows are part of the [Marvel Cinematic Universe (Earth 19999)](http://marvel.wikia.com/Earth-199999). They share a common timeline.

- Iron Man (1,2,3)
- Captain America (The First Avenger, Winter Soldier, Civil War)
- Thor (1, The Dark World, Ragnarok)
- The Avengers (1, Age of Ultron, Infinity War Part 1, Infinity War Part 2)
- Guardians of the Galaxy (1,2)
- Ant-Man
- The Incredible Hulk
- Marvel's Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.
- Marvel's Agent Carter
- Doctor Strange
- Black Panther
- Inhumans
- Daredevil
- Jessica Jones
- Luke Cage
- Iron Fist
- Spider-Man*

*As of 2015, [a special deal was struck between Sony and Marvel](http://screenrant.com/kevin-feige-spider-man-movie-plans/) allowing Spider-Man to appear within the MCU, and Marvel will be involved with the production of solo movies including the new Spider-Man movie.

The following existing movies/franchises are NOT part of the Marvel Cinematic Universe, as their movie rights are NOT owned by Marvel and thus not allowed to crossover without special agreements. Each separate universe has its own timeline (in the case of the X-Men movies, multiple timelines).

- The Sam Raimi Spider-Man Universe [Earth-96283](http://marvel.wikia.com/Earth-96283)
- The Amazing Spider-Man Universe [Earth-120703](http://marvel.wikia.com/Earth-120703)
- The X-Men Universe [Earth-10005](http://marvel.wikia.com/Earth-10005)
- The Fantastic Four Universe (2005 movie and Rise of the Silver Surfer) [Earth-121698](http://marvel.wikia.com/Earth-121698)
- The Ghost Rider Universe [Earth-121347](http://marvel.wikia.com/Earth-121347)
- The Daredevil/Elektra Universe [Earth-701306](http://marvel.wikia.com/Earth-701306)
- The Blade Universe [Earth-26320](http://marvel.wikia.com/Earth-26320)
- The Punisher Universe [Earth-58732](http://marvel.wikia.com/Earth-58732)
- The Ang Lee Hulk Universe [Earth-400083](http://marvel.wikia.com/Earth-400083)
- The Big Hero 6 Animated Universe [Earth-TRN441](http://marvel.wikia.com/Earth-TRN441)
- The Howard The Duck Universe [Earth-58470](http://marvel.wikia.com/Earth-58470)
- The Fantastic Four Universe (rebooted): [TRN554](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Fantastic_Four_(2015_film))

The new Fantastic Four movie is being rebooted/made by Fox Studios and will likely receive a new universe designation.

Since rights for Ghost Rider, Punisher, and Daredevil have now reverted back to Marvel, any *new* movies featuring them will likely be folded into the MCU (Earth 19999).

Comment: Wow - I knew about the MCU designation but didn't realize the Fox/Sony franchises had their own. Nice answer.

Comment: @Omegacron, As discussed [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/49641/what-is-the-criteria-for-receiving-an-official-marvel-universe-designation-movi/49644#49644), the non-MCU universes don't technically exist as far as Marvel is concerned. I haven't found exactly who designated those universe numbers. The real point is that each one is completely separate from the next.

Comment: I think i have my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Note: *The Hulk*, the Ang Lee film, is not part of the MCU.  *The Incredible Hulk* is though.

Comment: @Keen, IIRC, that was a weird case though. The Incredible Hulk was a *sort of* reboot that went to great lengths to not contradict the Ang Lee film.

Comment: @phantom42 The events of *The Incredible Hulk* are under the Marvel Studios banner, so they're part of the MCU.  *The Hulk* predates the Marvel Studios, ergo it cannot be part of the MCU.  It was a Universal production alone, just like *Spider-man*, *FF*, etc.

Comment: @phantom42 There's also the wildly different locations and setups of the two *Hulk's* origins.  One is in California, the other in Virgina.  One has a 'sins of the father' catalyst, the other has super-soldier aspirations.  What 'great lengths' did *TIH* go to to avoid contradicting *The Hulk*?

Comment: @keen, it's fine. I already fixed it. I know the second movie *takes place* largely in Virginia, but I don't recall it ever saying that the accident was there. They specifically avoided doing a new origin story and tried to keep details largely lined up.

Comment: @Keen you may be right though. I'm not an expert on the original Hulk movie because it was incredibly boring and I may have fallen asleep. The producers/writers tried to keep them in line where they could. [They see it as a "re-quel"](http://collider.com/entertainment/interviews/article.asp/aid/8230/tcid/1)

Comment: Supposedly, the current Fantastic Four and X-Men movies at Fox are a part of the same universe. Fox hired Mark Millar to do the "Joss Whedon" role of maintaining cohesion.

Comment: And the new Netflix series (Daredevil, Jessica Jones, Luke Cage, and Iron Fist) and the Defenders mini-series are all a part of the MCU.

Comment: Big Hero Six, and Howard the Duck are two more Marvel Comic Films that are not part of the MCU.

Comment: @krillgar They did hire Millar to help with that, but comments from Simon Kinberg not too long after that, [indicate that they will "complement" each other, but not share a universe](http://screenrant.com/fantastic-four-x-men-shared-universe/)

Comment: I'd like to add, because of a deal Marvel made with Sony, any new Spider-Man film *will* be part of the MCU, even while Spider-Man remains property of Sony. He was referenced in Ant-Man, will first appear in Civil War and there will be a movie in 2017. I always refer people to this wikipedia page. It contains a handy list of all movies in the MCU: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Cinematic_Universe#Films

Comment: The Fantastic Four reboot and the X-men films are in parallel realities, not separate universes, so a cross-over is possible. http://www.nydailynews.com/entertainment/movies/fantastic-x-men-not-film-universe-article-1.2314517