# Is Quicksilver in the X-Men movies the same as in Avengers: Age of Ultron?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, x-men-cinematic-universe, quicksilver

Ok, I have a couple of questions regarding Quicksilver, but it's all linked so...

1. Are the two Quicksilver characters from the *X-Men* movies and *Avengers: Age of Ultron* the same person? I thought Quicksilver had already made an [appearance in X2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X2_%28film%29#Comic_book_references), and was captured in *X-Men Origins: Wolverine*.

   I understand that in the Marvel Comics universe, Quicksilver was [raised by Magneto](https://marvel.com/universe/Quicksilver), but how will his origin or background be explained in *Avengers: Age of Ultron* when the X-Men are not in the cinematic Avengers universe? (And, if I remember correctly, the X-Men are deemed as outcasts/vigilantes by S.H.I.E.L.D. etc.)

   Maybe this is something that's explained in the X-Men vs Avengers books which I haven't read.
2. How come both Marvel and Fox have the rights to Quicksilver? I'm assuming Magneto or the X-Men won't be referenced in the upcoming *Avengers: Age of Ultron*.

I look forward to your answers and sources. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The X-Men vs Avengers books have nothing to do with either of the movies being produced (and they also don't go into their origins at all).

Comment: FYI - Quicksilver wasn't raised by Magneto, he was raised in the scientific citadel of Wundagore in the Balkan Mountains of the tiny European nation of Transia.  His mother Magda fled her husband, whom she knew as Erik, after a chilling display of his powers upon death of their daughter. She was then taken in by Bova, a humanoid cow evolved by the genetic engineer called the High Evolutionary.  After Magda died the children were given to Django Maximoff, by the High Evolutionary, to raise as his own.  Magneto didn't know about Pietro and Wanda for many-many years.

Comment: @22ndCenturyFza: “She was then taken in by Bova, a humanoid cow evolved by the genetic engineer called the High Evolutionary.” There are not enough upvotes in the world to do your comment justice.

Comment: This makes me curious, but I guess it has something to do with Marvel not quite having the rights to use X-Men in their movies... in Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D. (I think), there's some dialogue about whether some of the top brass believe in clairvoyance or other telepathy related things... if the X-Men are known vigilantes, wouldn't SHIELD know about Professor X? Or is the TV series possibly set before they learn of the Mutants' existence?

Comment: @22ndCenturyFza - Of course, since the *Avengers/X-Men: Axis* storyline, Pietro and Wanda are no longer Magneto's children, in the comics.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As discussed [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/17131/5184) and [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/49641/5184), the X-Men and Marvel Cinematic universes are entirely separate, and both are completely separate from all of the comics continuities (aside from any specific comic tie-ins created for the movies).

This means that neither cinematic universe is necessarily beholden to Quicksilver's comic past of being Magneto's son or Scarlet Witch's brother.

As laid out in the first linked post, Fox pretty much owns film rights to all "mutants", but an agreement exists that allows Marvel to use them provided that no reference is made to their traditional origins, and Fox cannot reference the Avengers in any way.

From an [interview with Kevin Feige](http://www.superherohype.com/features/170425-exclusive-interview-with-marvel-studios-prez-kevin-feige)

> SHH: What about the future of “The Avengers?” I don’t know if you want to bring in new characters or just keep the core team. Characters like the Scarlet Witch and Quicksilver, are they part of Fox’s deal or are they characters you could use?
>
> Feige: We both have them. **There’s a specific arrangement with those two characters that would allow us to use them with “Avengers,” but not discuss or reference their mutant or Magneto-related lineage. They can use them as mutants and as Magneto’s relatives, but cannot have anything to do with “The Avengers.”**

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the links. I'll check them out.

Comment: Huhm, [this version of Quicksilver](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_upF4Etvqv9Y/TI6O4ASTptI/AAAAAAAAGCA/sjIxrBY52p4/s1600/228364-128043-quicksilver_super.jpg) was rather prominent in that cartoon, and the target age group (mine) is now in their 20s.  I'm not so sure 90% is accurate...  ;)

Answer (score 7):

Just on this bit:

> how will his origin or background be explained in *Avengers: Age of Ultron*

I have a *Captain America: The Winter Soldier* spoiler for you. If you don’t want to get spoiled, look away now:

> In the mid-credits scene in Captain America 2, we see a HYDRA laboratory where scientists are experimenting on Loki’s staff. In a conversation regarding test subjects, a scientist asks what they intend to do with “the Twins”. We then see two cells, one containing a young chap who’s moving from place-to-place inside the cell very fast, the other containing a young woman apparently levitating and manipulating some cubes. ***That’s Quicksilver and Scarlett Witch OMG!!!! Oops, I spilled my popcorn.*** So, it looks like both Quicksilver and the Scarlett Witch in the Marvel Cinematic Universe will have originated from HYDRA experiments relating to Loki’s staff.

Comment: Oh that's really awesome :D Thanks for posting. I cant wait to see The Winter Soldier!

Comment: @Reanimation: you’re most welcome.

Answer (score -1):

No. However you could look at the two separate characters and safely assume that they are alternate realities, that Quicksilver occupies. I believe as one of Quicksilver's abilities he can go forward and back in time and is multi-dimensional, creating multiples of himself that are placed in different parts of time and realities so he can jump back and forth. If they ever make a combination movie that would be one of he ways they could link the two franchises, through Quicksilver's abilities enhanced by his sister. So far the marvel franchise is denying any relation and that they do not have any plans of linking the two together currently.

> We’ve known that the pair of new heroes joining The Avengers 2 are the “brother-sister act” of Quicksilver and Scarlet Witch (a third new character, Vision is also joining the fray) and in the comics, they’re mutants, the children of X-Men antagonist Magneto, characters all owned by Twentieth Century Fox. Due to complicated film rights issues, these two characters are an odd exception to the rule and can be used by both Marvel and Fox. For Marvel Studios however, they can only use them in a limited capacity since they don’t own “mutants” or X-Men characters like “Magneto” which means, new origins and new source of powers.
>
> > “Well, Inhumans is something that we are definitely thinking about and we think there’s great potential there for a great movie. But, no, no — we have not linked those two.”
> >
> > > http://screenrant.com/avengers-2-ultron-scarlet-witch-quicksilver-story/

Comment: When quoting a source, we generally ask that the source be named (what magazine/site/paper was interviewing, etc) and if possible, a link be provided. This helps make your answer more credible.

Comment: I don't ever remember Quicksilver remotely fast enough to cross dimensional barriers.  I seem to remember him only ever being able to hit Mach I, or thereabouts.

Answer (score -4):

Quicksilver and the Scarlett Witch are considered mutants, therefore Fox has the right to use them.  However, since they also appeared in the Avengers comics, Marvel can use them, too.  The difference is that they CANNOT be referred to as mutants, so their origins were changed to make the Inhumans, a Kree experiment on genetically-modified humans earlier in Earth's history, who generally keep apart from "normal" humans.

Comment: Do you have a source for where it's stated they are now Inhumans as opposed to mutants for the MCU?

Comment: This rumor [has been debunked by Kevin Feige](http://www.cinemablend.com/new/Avengers-Age-Ultron-Won-t-Have-Quicksilver-Scarlet-Witch-Inhumans-42079.html).