# Are Rory Williams And Rip Hunter the same person?

Tags: doctor-who, dc, arrowverse, legends-of-tomorrow

Both Rory Williams And Rip Hunter are both played by the same actor—Arthur Darvill—and both play a man who's traveled through time and space. One traveled with a Time Lord called the Doctor and one is a Timemaster who's assembled a team to stop Vandal Savage. 
But they both have the same face. Because when Rip said:

> Rip: I've seen darker days. I've seen men of steel die and dark knights fall, and even then I accomplished my mission no matter what.

That made me think the darker days Rip saw were all the adventures he had with the Doctor and Amy from series 5-7 of *Doctor Who* and his piloting of the wavrider is similar  to the Doctor so I thought after leaving the Doctor with Amy after NewYork with the Weeping Angels he lived to 2166 and changed his name from Rory to Rip Hunter and had his wife and son Miranda and Jonas, then they died at the hands of Vandal Savage.  Rip then takes the waverider and you know the rest. Another theory is Rory might have traveled through the multiverse to the DC TV universe and changed his name to Rip Hunter. The last theory is that when Rory was touched by the Weeping Angel he was transported to the DC TV universe in  Central City.

Are Rory Williams And Rip Hunter the same person ?

Comment: is this a really cool theory and question

Comment: no. it's silly, because obviously, no.

Comment: Not cool man not cool

Comment: This question is a bit like asking if Ethan Hunt (*Mission Impossible*) and Roy Millerand (*Knight and Day*) are the same character because they are both secret agents played by Tom Cruise. For that matter, Jack Reacher might as well be the same character too.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Probably not

There are a few reasons that Rory and Rip are unlikely to be the same person.

1. Rory Williams is from *Doctor Who*, whereas Rip Hunter is from the Arrowverse.
2. Just because two characters are played by the same actor, doesn't mean that they are the same character. For example:

   - Meryl Streep plays Margaret Thatcher in *The Iron Lady*, and the witch in *Into the Woods*. This does not mean that Margaret Thatcher was literally a sorceress.
   - Arthur Darvill also plays Edward Dorrit in *Little Dorrit*, Bradley Burroughs in *The Paradise*, and a host of other roles. Should we believe that all these people were secretly Rory in disguise, even those who were obviously older and clearly had full-fledged backstories, quite different from those of Rory?
3. Further, Rory is not immortal (seeing as he is no longer plastic). He is a ordinary human, and as such, would have had trouble living to the year 2166.
4. Rory would not simply have abandoned Amy, nor would Amy have abandoned Rory. Far more than that—judging from Rory's characterization in *Doctor Who*, he would have been incapable of moving on from Amy to another partner. Not only was she the only person he ever showed any romantic interest in, but he waited several millenia for her. A century or two probably wouldn't change his mind.
5. The Weeping Angels send people back in time, not to alternate universes.

Comment: what about when rip said  I've seen darker days. I've seen men of steel die and dark knights fall, and even then I accomplished my mission no matter what.

Comment: @AndrewCasali - You're free to have that within your own headcanon. Mine is different.

Comment: @AndrewCasali - "Men of steel" is a reference to Superman. "Dark knights"  is a reference to Batman.

Comment: what is headcanon

Comment: @AndrewCasali - What one believes to be true about a work of fiction.

Comment: i thought  the darker days rip sawed were all the adventures he had with the doctor and amy from series 5-7 of doctor who

Comment: Or, you know, they're darker days he saw as Rip Hunter... You can think it means Doctor Who if you want, but that doesn't make it plausible.

Comment: Are you saying Margaret Thatcher *wasn't* a witch?!?

Comment: @Randal'Thor No no no. Jonah is saying you can't put the blame on Meryl Streep.

Comment: I think definitely  suits better then Probably here.

Comment: Also didn't Rory and Amy spend their last days together when they were sent back in time by the angels.

Comment: “Arthur Darvill also plays Edward Dorrit in Little Dorrit, Bradley Burroughs in The Paradise, and a host of other roles. Should we believe that all these people were secretly Rory in disguise, even those who were obviously older and clearly had full-fledged backstories, quite different from those of Rory?” No — but I delight in believing that [Stan Lee is playing The Watcher secretly in disguise](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/76303/is-stan-lee-playing-the-watcher-in-all-his-cameos) in all his Marvel movie appearances, even though he’s not.

Comment: If they were the same, that would mean he's willing to thoroughly mess up history to save his wife Miranda and his son Jonas, but not his wife Amy and daughter Melody. Make of that what you will.

Answer (score -1):

Pretty unrealistic as noted by previous comments. However, I would not be able to deny that perhaps that they are related in a way.
Both the Arrowverse (like the comics it is based on) as well as Doctor Who both have displayed that parallel universes exist.
Following the rules of the DC and Marvel multiverses, Rory and Rip might as well be the same person from an entirely different universe and timeline.
You see, according to DC and Marvel, every universe has an infinite number of parallel universes, these are all part of one big Multiverse, which then is part of one Omniverse and Blah Blah Blah.
This means that DC has its own set of universes contained in the DC universe and so on.
If you keep that in mind, EVERYTHING is connected, meaning that Rory and Rip would very likely be the same person, just in different universes, with different history, laws of space and time and so on.