# What is the correct timeline for Captain America: Civil War and Guardians of the Galaxy: Vol. 2?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-civil-war, guardians-of-the-galaxy-2

We saw Stan Lee appear twice in Guardians 2; the first time is during the 700 hyperspace jumps, with one of the realms they speed through featuring Lee telling stories to a trio of Watchers (specifically when he was a FedEx agent in *Captain America: Civil War*.)

Now, it was revealed to us that Guardians 2 took place in 2014. However, *Captain America: Civil War* was released in 2016. We know that most MCU movies take place during real life present time. If this is the case for Civil War, is there any explanation for this?

Comment: Related: [Is Stan Lee playing the Watcher in all his cameos?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/76303/21267)

Comment: Also, definitely not a "plot hole": http://imgur.com/gallery/L7zDu

Comment: Technically the older of the questions, but the answer on the newer one has a better, WoG answer.

Answer (score 8):

As I explained in my [answer on M&TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/72766/did-guardians-of-the-galaxy-vol-2-confirm-that-marvel-now-has-the-rights-to-fant/72767#72767), Stan Lee's character's comment about playing a Fed Ex agent really tells us nothing at all about the timing of that scene:

> As far as Lee's cameo, it's possible that he was a Fed-EX agent more than once in his "career" -- if a disguise works well enough, why not keep using it?

This was a throw-away line, essentially an Easter Egg (showing Lee as a Watcher's informant), and as such, it's almost trivial for Marvel to explain it away:

> Even if he was talking about Civil War, Marvel's Easter Eggs rarely follow their canon timeline as much as they should, and often get sloppily ret-conned away later -- the "totally not Adam Warlock's cocoon" from Guardians vol. 1, or Stephen Strange discussing a case about "totally not Rhodes" accident are two other examples. If pressed, Marvel will probably do the same with Lee's comment.

Comment: Read your answer. Thank you for this.

Comment: Also, "totally not the Infinity Gauntlet in Odin's treasure room".