# Is there any precedent for time travel in the MCU?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, time-travel

Is there any time travel in the MCU

> aside from the time travel that the Avengers use in *Endgame* to undo the effects of Thanos' snap?

Answer (score 12):

### There might be previous examples, depending on definition

In *Doctor Strange*, Strange has a time loop that resets the entirety of the Dark Dimension. Effectively, this sends him back in time, but since it doesn't only affect him and resets his physical state as opposed to leaving it unchanged, it's not conventional.

Similarly, being able to see the future, as some of the sorcerers can do, might be considered a form of informational time travel.

### If we count the extended MCU, definitely yes

- *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.* had a extended time travel plotline involving the Kree in its fifth and most recent season, presumably as part of the tie-in to *Infinity War*.
- *Runaways* had a message sent back to the past (informational time travel).

Comment: Depending on how much inference you're willing to take, there's the Stan Lee cameo in GotG2, which has been taken to mean that he's a "Watcher" (apparently endorsed by Feige). I believe that there are time travel elements to that, too.

Comment: The time loop from Doctor Strange doesn't reset the entirety of the Dark Dimension; it resets Doctor Strange's time frame; that's how Dormammu knows it's being reset and thus drives him to accept the bargain. The Dark Dimension exists outside of time.

Comment: @TylerH - Hmmm, that could be it too.

Comment: @JozefWoods - Feige has not confirmed that he is the Watcher (or part of the group shown) -https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/76303/is-stan-lee-playing-the-watcher-in-all-his-cameos - merely that it's *likely* he is the same character in all MCU films. Also note, in that space scene, he clearly requires life support whereas the other aliens do not - further implying he isn't one of their race (at least)

Comment: @Adamant the most recent season of AoS also featured time travel as a goal for a previously peaceful, but now malevolent, race known as Chromicons. At the end of the season, the team develops time travel themselves, which it appears season 7 will use heavily.

Answer (score 0):

### **There is at least one example in the MCU films**

Thanos reversing time so that he could get the Mind Stone from Vision's head. He travels into an alternate version of the past when he does that.

Comment: Did he actually travel into the past or just reverse the flow of time to restore Vision and the mind stone?

Comment: _"He travels into an alternate version of the past when he does that."_ - errrm I don't think this is correct at all. He just reverses time on the Vision death event like we see Strange doing with the apple.