# What are the other versions of earth in the Marvel universe/multiverse?

Tags: marvel

Under the [marvel-comics](/questions/tagged/marvel-comics) tag I have seen many questions on earth-616. Are there any other versions of earth as well? How do they differ from each other?

Comment: Very related: [What is the criteria for receiving an official Marvel universe designation?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/49641/5184) and [What is the difference between Marvel's Ultimate universe (Earth-1610) and the Cinematic universe (Earth-199999)?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/17131/5184)

Comment: It's infinite, or practically infinite, look at how many Captain Britain's there are in the multiverse corps: http://i491.photobucket.com/albums/rr273/Inanna/Friends%20and%20allies/corps-2.jpg

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many, many more - there is a list of them on the [Marvel wikia](http://marvel.wikia.com/Multiverse/Universe_Listing).

The main ones are:

- Earth-616 - Main Marvel Universe
- Earth-1610 - Ultimate Marvel
- Earth-148611 - New Universe (Home reality of Justice, Nightmask, Star Brand and Spitfire and the Troubleshooters.)
- Earth-555 - newuniversal (reboot of the above)
- Earth-45828 - Razorline (Clive Barker's Razorline imprint)
- Earth-88194 - Shadowline (Home reality of Doctor Zero, Power Line, and St. George and origin of Terror)
- Earth-93060 - Ultraverse (Malibu Comics)
- Earth-818793 - Army of Darkness
- Earth-8311 - Larval Universe (spider-ham etc)
- Earth-928 - Marvel 2099
- Earth-295 - Age of Apocalypse
- Earth-982 - MC2
- Earth-92131 - Marvel Animated    (X-Men: The Animated Series)
- Earth-199999 - Marvel Cinematic Universe (MCU)
- Earth-2149 - Marvel Zombies

More difference detail on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiverse_%28Marvel_Comics%29#Known_alternate_universes).