# Is Magneto the Maximoff twins’ father in Age of Ultron?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe

In *Avengers: Age of Ultron*, is the Maximoff twins’ father Magneto?

Because in the comics he is, but in the movie they said the Maximoff twins’ parents died, and Magneto would not really die that easily, so is he their father?

Comment: Potential duplicate : http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/52589/is-quicksilver-in-the-x-men-movies-the-same-as-in-avengers-age-of-ultron

Comment: @AncientSwordRage I disagree about that being a duplicate. The other question is about if they are the same in the X-Men movies and the Marvel Cinematic Universe, while this question is about if one aspect is the same between the comics and the MCU.

Comment: This is _not_ a dupe. :) It's asking if Magneto is their father in both the MCU and XCU. Different questions. :)

Comment: It would require magneto to be in the MCU which the answer in the question explains he isn't, I believe.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage It's asking whether the twins are the children of __a__ Magneto in the MCU. It's _not_ asking if the XCU Magneto is their father, rather it's asking whether their MCU father is a guy who is/becomes an MCU version of Magneto, or is the father someone else.

Comment: My point is *any* version of Magneto would be property of the foxverse. Unlike the characters themselves,  whom have been *split* so to speak.

Comment: @RedCaio: duplicate questions on here are classified as questions which are already answered by an answer on another question. [The accepted answer on 52589](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/52589/is-quicksilver-in-the-x-men-movies-the-same-as-in-avengers-age-of-ultron/52594#52594) has a quote from Kevin Feige answering the Magneto question.

Comment: In the comics, as of AXIS: Avengers/X-Men, when it comes to twins Wanda  and Pietro, Magneto is NOT the father! (insert crowd from Maury booing and hissing).

Comment: @AncientSwordRage Well, it would only require that the character of their father be named "Max Eisenhardt" or "Erik Lehnsherr". The first may or may not be a name licensed to 20th Century Fox. But, I agree that the current license agreements left Marvel saying "No Magneto here" for The Twins.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite As I read that answer, it only says that they _can_ follow the comics but don't _have to_. Or am I misreading that?

Comment: @SQB: my understanding is that this question is asking whether Magneto is Quicksilver’s and Scarlett Witch’s father in *Age of Ultron*, and [that answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/52594/440) says “There’s a specific arrangement with those two characters that would allow us to use them with “Avengers,” but not discuss or reference their mutant or Magneto-related lineage” — in other words, nope, Magneto’s not their father in *Age of Ultron*.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Yes, but: "[t]hey can use them as mutants and as **Magneto’s relatives**, but cannot have anything to do with _The Avengers._" (emphasis mine). --- nevermind, read that the wrong way around.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't believe there are enough facts about their father to say definitively Yes or No.

The only facts known at this point are

- The twins are considered orphans.
- A mortar shell struck their home. I believe the dialogue was something like "Blew a hole in the ground and our parents fell in", so maybe that leaves wiggle room for some "He survived somehow", but I doubt it.
- There is no evidence of their father having any special powers.
- Their powers were unlocked by the Scepter. Whether that has anything to do with their father has not been clarified in this universe (unlike, say, Peter Quill, where we know his father's identity has something to do with his abilities).
- He is never named.

Whether it's relevant is another matter entirely since they presumably they cannot use him in any meaningful way, hence why killing him off was an easy option.

Comment: +1 Magneto is considered the twins' father in _X-Men_ universe but there is no mention of such relation in _Avengers: Age of Ultron_ (otherwise he would just show up and terminate the robots, he is Magneto ffs). In [here](http://marvel.com/news/comics/22063/trace_the_roots_of_magnetos_family_tree), you can read about Magneto's family lines in comics-verse.

Comment: We've been told by the head of marvel studios that nothing magneto related can exist in the MCU. See my answer to this question.

Comment: It would be easy enough to say the dead parents were the ones that raised them, but their biological father is Magneto. But since Marvel doesn't have the film rights to Magneto, it's wishful thinking either way.

Comment: Nothing Magneto related can be referenced or discussed. That is completely different to "Nothing Magneto related can exist". It's intentional wordplay which leave it sufficiently vague, with NO concrete answer

Answer (score 6):

My answer is based off of this [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/52594/3804), which I think makes this question a duplicate:

> As discussed [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/17131/5184) and [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/49641/5184), the X-Men and Marvel Cinematic universes are entirely separate,
>
> This means that neither cinematic universe is necessarily beholden to Quicksilver's comic **past of being Magneto's son**
>
> an agreement exists that allows Marvel to use them provided that **no reference is made to their traditional origins**
>
> From an [interview with Kevin Feige](http://www.superherohype.com/features/170425-exclusive-interview-with-marvel-studios-prez-kevin-feige)
>
> > Feige: We both have them. **There’s a specific arrangement ... *not [to] discuss or reference their mutant or Magneto-related lineage.* ”**

Emphasis mine. Note that last part. That precludes any MCU version of Magneto existing mutant or otherwise.

That only conclusion is that the MCU twins have some other non-magneto-related lineage.

Comment: To be pedantic, that doesn't preclude Magneto fathering Quicksilver in the MCU, it merely prohibits MCU from talking about that fact if it is the case - which is in turn not contradicted by the vague 'parents died' line that's been trotted out.  Wiggle room in case the two franchises get closer?

Comment: @gowenfawr right, by simply not mentioning it it can still be something else later. They can pull the old you were actually adopted trick

Comment: Admittedly they could,  after a merger retcon the events,  but answers shouldn't have to account for potential future retcons.

Comment: "This means that neither cinematic universe is necessarily beholden to Quicksilver's comic past of being Magneto's son".
In age of Ultron there was no mention of him being the son, but in X-Men first class Quicksilver does make a comment about a man, that, according to comics, was his father, that met the description of Magneto.

Comment: Xmen first class is not part of the MCU.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage At the same time you can not make absolute assumptions "That only conclusion is that the MCU twins have some other non-magneto-related lineage" based on the available information

Comment: @AncientSwordRage In-fact a rather cheeky way of reading "not [to] discuss or reference their mutant or Magneto-related lineage" is "Of course he is their father... We just can't make reference to that fact!"

Comment: @curiousdannii The quote I referenced from above points to Non-MCU X-Men content. So my point still stands valid. He made a  generalization.